# Convex Hull generation for a collection of x,y co-ordinates in Postgres + postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial, postgresql-9.3, spatial-query

I need to be able to create a table and store a few x,y co-ordinates as a geometry and then be able to generate a convex hull for these points.

This is what I have so far

```
CREATE TABLE global_points ( 
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(64),
location GEOMETRY(POINT,4326));
```

But I'm not too sure about it. How do I insert my collection x,y co-ordinates to this table and then generate a convex hull for this geometry?

Need to do this using potsgis spatial database extension for postgres

Comment: Show your code. The question doesn't give any hints as to why convex hull is somehow connected with you inserting data into a table. Maybe you wanted to ask how to do an INSERT in sql?

Answer (score 3):

You should give more information about the way you want to add points to your table. Here is an example with some random points.

**1) Insert data into your table**

```
--insert points using geographical coordinates
INSERT INTO global_points (name, location) VALUES
('point1', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-5, 25), 4326)),
('point2', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.2, -2.3), 4326)),
('point3', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(5.3, 21), 4326)),
('point4', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(2, 12), 4326));
```

**2) Compute the convex hull from a collection of points**

```
--get the convex hull
SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(location)) AS convex_hull
FROM global_points;
```